# Global variable not incremented (is gcc nuts?)

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have the following stupid code: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/VarqjH)

Can somebody explain, why the hack the global counter does not increment when deleting the objects A in the std::vector ???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int global;

class A {
public:
    A(int i): a(i) {}
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "delete A" << std::endl;
        ++global;
    };
    int foo() {
        return a;
    }
    int a;
};


int main() {


        int c = 0;
        int loops = 10;
        global = 0;

        // Make vector of pointers
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A> > vec;
        for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
            vec.push_back( std::shared_ptr<A>(new A(i))    );
        }

        for(int i=0; i<loops; i++) {
            for(auto & p : vec) {
                c += p->foo();
            }
        }

        std::cout << " deleted:" << global << std::endl;

}
```

**Output:**

```
 deleted:0
delete A
delete A
```

Comment: The `A` objects are deleted *after* you print `global` to `cout`.

Answer (score 5):

The `A` objects are deleted *after* you print `global` to `cout`.

Comment: ooh damm stupid, argg, thanks